# Reflexivity of transitive relation with no right end point on finite models

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm trying to prove $\forall x\exists y Pxy$ plus transitivity of $P$ implies $\exists x Pxx$ and possibly $\forall xPxx$ if we consider finite models only.

To prove this, I defined $P_ixy\leftrightarrow \exists z_1 \cdots\exists z_{i-1} (Pxz_1\wedge Pz_1 z_2\wedge...\wedge Pz_{i-1}y$) which means there are $i$ steps to go from $x$ to $y$. Then I fixed $a$ (in any given finite model) and collected $b$ such that $Pab$ and made hierarchy of $P_1 P_2 ... P_n$. Since a model is finite here, there must be at most finite $n$ of $P_i$ relations from $a$. I thought there should be some particular relations between elements in $P_i$ but I cannot proceed anymore from here.

Comment: Certainly not $\forall$.  Consider $P12$, $P13$, $P22$, $P23$, $P32$, $P33$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are on the right track.  You can show $\forall i\forall x\exists yP_ixy$.  Then consider an $i$ larger than the size of your model.  By the Pigeonhole principle, you must have $z_j=z_k$ for some $j,k\le i$, and then you can deduce $Pz_jz_j$.

Comment: Truly amazing. Thanks!